# Regex with different results

Tags: regex

I trying some regex coding and I need your help.

**Here my code and my test :**

Regex : `\b\d{4}[\.\-/\\ _]{0,2}\d{2,4}(/\d{2,4}){0,}`

String : `... chemical tank 6211-10/20/30/40 and other equipment ...`

Result : `6211-10/20/30/40`

**What I am expected :**

```
-6211-10
-6211-10/20
-6211-10/20/30
-6211-10/20/30/40
```

I have found something interesting like :
`(?:/\d{2,4})` which gave me /20 , /30 and /40 but I dunno how to concatenate several regex in one  condition.

The number of tags can change, `6311-22/42` or `6158-47/84/85/86/87/88/89` for samples.

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is use the [regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (install using `pip install regex`) with a lookbehind and a capture group to get the values.

```
\b(?<=(\d{4}[./\\ _-]{0,2}\d{2,4}(?:\/\d{2,4})*))
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to assert what to the left is

  - `(` Capture **group 1**, this value will be returned by findall)

    - `\d{4}[./\\ _-]{0,2}\d{2,4}` Match the pattern with the digits and 0-2 occurrences of the character class
    - `(?:\/\d{2,4})*` Optionally repeat `/` and 2-4 digits
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close the lookbehind

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/coxWqY/1) or a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LYxLDoIwFAD3nOKFVWugLZ@4MBIOYo2p8JRGKLXUREM4e@2C3WSSGfvzw2yqEPRkZ@fB4RO/oJYISbJAAyljDLoBJ92pEbwyLziWRZEXgpeCV4LXApTpYfYDOsD3R9sJjYeYpYlV3qMzceNSeSftuSGyX@vtwriUcMuvq8jKLaoyqzfSnviO9EBprJ02njhkD216NY5k32WwUBrCHw).

For example

```
import regex as re

s = "... chemical tank 6211-10/20/30/40 and other equipment ..."
pattern = r"\b(?<=(\d{4}[./\\ _-]{0,2}\d{2,4}(?:/\d{2,4})*))"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['6211-10', '6211-10/20', '6211-10/20/30', '6211-10/20/30/40']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test your regular expressions online. For example regex101.com can help you.

I have saved your expression and corrected it here:
https://regex101.com/r/YX1X0f/1

You have to escape the `/` in your regular expression, because it is a delimiter:
`\b\d{4}[\.\-/\\ _]{0,2}\d{2,4}(\/\d{2,4}){0,}`

This matches all your scenarios (also see link above).

Comment: Thanks for your replying, well, I should be more specify. My scenario is the text "... chemical tank 6211-10/20/30/40 and other equipment ...". What I am trying to get is 6211-10 and 6211-10/20 ... . My regular expression only gave me one match, what I wanted is several match like https://regex101.com/r/ezgMcY/1 . One of the result should be like https://regex101.com/r/AvB2wI/1. Thank for the link, very useful !

Comment: Oh so you need to capture each one as a separate group? Then you will have to repeat how ever many groups there can be. Like `\b\d{4}[\.\-/\\ _]{0,2}\d{2,4}(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?(\/\d{2,4})?` Unless other answers correct me this is the only way I know how to capture each one individually.